# How to close a single screen/page in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

There is `Qt.quit()`which exits the application but I just want to exit the current screen which should let me go back to the parent screen. How do I do that?

```
Rectangle {
    id: page
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 480

    Button {
        width: 150
        height: 50
        text: "Parent"

        onClicked: {
            console.log("Parent pressed")

            //? how to exit this screen here?
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the new code after Folibis answer.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360

    property bool isClose: false

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if(isClose)
                 Qt.quit();
             else
                 Page2.show() //subWindow.show();
             isClose = true;
        }
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

The Window is in new qml file now named Page2.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: subWindow
    visible: false
    width: 400
    height: 400
    flags: Qt.Dialog
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Click me to close the subwindow"
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: subWindow.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is how to I call Page2.qml from main.qml?

Comment: Maybe just `page.visible = false` ?

Comment: That will work only if the `rectangle` is in same file, I want to return from another qml file.

Comment: Look into StackView: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the right way to organize windows in application is to use appropriate components.
`Rectangle` as window is not useful and also not semantic. Use `Window` for dialogs and secondary windows and `ApplicationWindow` as a main window. As a bonus you have all useful function to manage it.

Example:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    id: mainWindow
    property bool isClose: false
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: isClose ? "Click me to close the main window" : "Click me to show subwindow"
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if(isClose)
                Qt.quit();
            else
                subWindow.show();
            isClose = true;
        }
    }
    Window {
        id: subWindow
        visible: false
        width: 400
        height: 400
        flags: Qt.Dialog
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Click me to close the subwindow"
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: subWindow.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I move subWindow to a new qml file? I did that to `Page2.qml` and than in the above `Page2.show()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sure, you can move the window to any place you want. Show the code when you create and close the window, probably you miss somesing

Comment: But id doesn't work. I defined the `Window`module in another page2.qml file. How do I show that?

Comment: Please show corresponding code, otherwise it is very difficult to say where the problem

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. You have to understand difference between declaration of object and instance of object. In your case Page2.qml is just a declaration, this structure is not exist in memory. So you need to instance the object. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Instancing the new window

```
var component = Qt.createComponent("Page2.qml");
if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
    var subWindow = component.createObject(mainWindow);
    conn.target = subWindow;
    subWindow.show();
}

Connections {
    id: conn
    onVisibleChanged: {
        if(visible)
            console.log("window closed");
    }
}
```

as a bonus - code to trigger window closing event